# How to make bixby read the card?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

Is there any way i can make bixby to read information on my card. Like if my card has title, date, description, so after bixby read the message "Here is what i found", it should read like "India vs Australia, Green park, Kanpur, 10th March, 1:30 PM".

Is it possible to add speech in `result-view`? I am showing like 6 cards on one result and want bixby to read all of them one by one and need like 3-4 seconds pause between each cards.

I am showing `compound card` in my `result-view` and using `single-line`. Adding speech in template resulting nothing. I am adding few lines of my code.

```
list-of (all) {
  has-details (false)
    where-each (single) {
        compound-card {
           content {
             single-line {
                if (exists(single.Name)){
                  text {
                    value {
                      template ("#{value(single.Name)}"){
                        speech("#{value(single.Name)}")
                      }
                    }
                    style (Title_S)
                   }
                 }
               }
             }
           }
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to define the `speech` key of your dialog template ([documentation link](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/template.speech)). This can be different from what the dialog template text says so you can customize it as needed. Your `speech` did not work since it needs to be a part of the dialog template.

**Adding more information after initial question was modified:**

[Hands-free List Navigation](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/enhancing-UX.list-navigation) would be the correct way for you to enable a voice output for every entry in a summary mode `result-view`. This allows you to choose a few different ways the summary content will be read to the user and how the user can select one of the options.

Comment: Have added few more details in my question. please review.

Comment: Great! I've added some more information to my initial answer.

Comment: I have implemented the navigation mode but it speaks only the message which is in item-selection-question and nothing?

Comment: I think I may have found the exact section that will help you. I'll add it to the answer when I confirm its behavior.

Comment: I'm currently discussing the functionality that I believe will allow you to achieve the behavior you'd like with the team. I will provide some code that will help you as soon as I've confirmed it!

Comment: Thanks... I have posted 2 more questions... Please check it